# CloudWatch - create an alarm to monitor CPUUtilization of production servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

Let's say I have several EC2 instances with the `environment=production` tags on them. I know I can create a graph with the "metrics explorer" that will aggregate the *CPUUtilization*  of all those EC2 instances based on this tag. However, I can't see an option to set an alarm on this aggregate.

I also know that I can set an alarm on a *Metrics Insights* query, but as far as I know I cannot, using the Metrics Insight query, get this aggregate of CPUUtilization of instanes based on tag.

So my question is, say I want to have an alarm on the aggregated CPUUtilization of those instances, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you filter your EC2 instance on `metrics explorer` then on dashboard click three dots and `View on metrics`.

[image: View on metrics]

it will display all EC2 instances with one additional graphed metrics with name `All resources` with value `AVG([m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12, m13])`.

[image: All resources metric]

Then you can create your alarm from this new aggregated metric.

> Note: This metric will not be dynamic a metric, when you create a new instance with `environment=production` tag, it will not be include.

Comment: Your answer is poorly worded, please fix it

Comment: Please check newly added SS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an alarm on an expression that depends on more than 10 metrics.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).